# pthread was not found

Tags: include, pthreads

I am working on pthread in C++ using visual studio 2008. I have a problem because the compiler does not find . I knew that it was embedded in C++ 2005. Do i have to install the library and add it manually or it should be installed with C++ default libraries?
If i have to install it, please give me the url.
Hani Almousli

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any reference that says that Visual C++ ever included a POSIX thread library.  Perhaps you were using a third-party library, like [this one](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/).

Answer (score 0):

pthreads is not included in C++ nor visual studio. It's the threading system/library usually found on unix systems.

If you want pthreads for windows, go to http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a page on creating threads in Visual C++ .NET or in Visual C++ 2005:

[How to create threads in Visual C++ .NET or in Visual C++ 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815805)

This might be of some help?